# Is there a way to reverse lookup which executable is being called?

Tags: batch-file, path, environment-variables, cmd.exe

I have multiple JDK's installed on my machine and I'm running on a system that has a pretty long path environment variable. Is there a way to see what my call to java resolves to?

I'm looking for something that works like this, or can help me do the same thing:

```
 C:\> set path=c:\program files\java\jre1.8.0.20\bin\;%path%;
 C:\> lookup java
 java => c:\program files\java\jre1.8.0.20\bin\java.exe

 C:\> set path=c:\program files(x86)\java\jre1.8.0.20\bin\;%path%;
 C:\> lookup java
 java => c:\program files(x86)\java\jre1.8.0.20\bin\java.exe
```

I can probably figure it out through the task manager, open process location etc, but I'd love to be able to wrap this into a script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest option is to use the WHERE command - however, it is fairly slow. By default, it lists all possible matching files within the current directory and within the PATH directories. It searches using the argument given, and also searches with each of the PATEXT extensions appended.

```
where java
```

The first file listed represents the file that would be executed. This value can change depending on your current directory. A simple batch script can be used to return only the file that would execute. I've written the script to take the command as the 1st and only argument. So it can be used to locate any external command.

```
@echo off
for %%F in ('where "%~1"') do (
  echo %%F
  exit /b
)
```

Assuming the script is called WHICH1.BAT, then usage would be

```
which1 java
```

There is a faster method using the `%~f$PATH:1` expansion. However, you must know the extension of the executable file. Also, it does not normally look in the current directory. So it is best to create a temporary modified PATH that includes the current directory at the front. It is unlikely, but one of the paths within PATH could contain unquoted poison characters, so I use delayed expansion. But then there is the unlikely possibility that a path could contain `!`, which would be corrupted with delayed expansion, so I disable it again. The final result is quoted to protect against poison characters.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "modPath=.;!path!"
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
echo "%~f$modPath:1"
```

If the above script is WHICH2.BAT, then usage is

```
which2 java.exe
```

All of the above scripts will not recognize internal commands.

I have written a robust [WHICH.BAT script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11014252/1012053) that will properly list a command as internal when appropriate, otherwise it will list the external command that would be executed.

Usage is

```
which java
```

Comment: That's just perfect. I can make do with just `where` it already granted me some interesting insights. Turns out that `java.exe` from the `windoes\system32` folder is being used.